# How to cast the response body to POJO class when it's error and make it able to accept when the response body is null with Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I made a helper funtion to hit another rest service.

```
    public BaseResponse doPostService(String url, Object body) throws Exception {
        RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
        try {
            ResponseEntity<BaseResponse> r = rest.postForEntity(url, body, BaseResponse.class);
            return r.getBody();
        } catch (RestClientResponseException e) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            // I want to return the Response body caught here
            return mapper.readValue(e.getResponseBodyAsString(), BaseResponse.class);
            
        } catch (ResourceAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

However, I got issue when the result of `e.getResponseBodyAsString()` can't be parsed to that class. Is there any possible trick to get it work without the need of creating new method?

Comment: It is an error not your response so how should that even work? Also this method is wrong as you shouldn't be instantiating a `RestTemplate` each time you need one, nor the `ObjectMapper`. That being said if your `BaseResonse` is some abstract class you could create a specific one for exceptions and parse that, however you are at the mercy of your server that way and hope the error/exception never changes.

Comment: Naturally, that ResponseEntity regards the 400, 404, 500 responses as error. However, in my case, the body returned from that error responses are necessary. How to tackle this? @M.Deinum

Comment: @M.Deinum Is it also possible to regard the 400, 401, 403, 404, 500, 504 responses as "normal" instead of being thrown to Exception. In my case, the service that my service need to use gives important message as there may have different cause for such response.

Comment: No. I suggest you also readup on how JSON (de)serialization works. If the incoming json doesn't match it will never match your object. So i highly doubt that your error json is the same as the normal JSON.